# How to write custom annotation for getting the request parameters - Not using filters [ spring java]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a use case where I want to check if a request has a particular query parameter or not and I can't change the signature of current controller method.

E.g

I have controller method like

```
@PutMapping(path = Constants.ControllerEndPoint)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> controllerMethod(
        @RequestParam(name = objectId) String objectId,
        @RequestBody Flux<DataBuffer> objectData)
```

Now I want to check if there is no **objectName** parameter passed so to check that I do not want to change the controllerMethod signature. I want to add a annotation before the method and extract the request parameter there to see if any objectName parameter is passed in the request or not.

like this ->

```
@PutMapping(path = Constants.ControllerEndPoint)
**@NoObjectName(@RequestParam ( name= ApiConstants.objectName))**
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> controllerMethod(
        @RequestParam(name = objectId) String objectId,
```

I'm not sure how to do this ? Is there a way if I can get the requestParameter value in the annotation target class or any other way to do the validation ?

I tried creating an annotation and tried passing the request parameter but that did not work, perhaps somewhere I'm not passing the values correctly or may be I do not understand the annotation way of implementation correctly.

Comment: Why you don't want to change the method's signature?

Comment: Because that will then change the api:spec and which will need a whole lot of approvals to get it through. :)

Comment: And what needs to happen if the parameter isn't there?

Comment: @Zelocox if you are putting the parameter anyway, doesn't api/spec also change? If you won't put it in the signature but still require it, doesn't it mean that the api/spec also changes?

Comment: @Barracuda : For a general get request - as a client you can add as many parameters as you want and on the server side you will just check for the ones you need right and not all. Similarly - I just want to check for a particular parameter which is not part of the spec which I have published already. 
Now, adding the parameter to signature will violate some constraints I've added on my controller methods ( api/spec).

Comment: @M.Deinum : If its not there, I'm good but if its there I want to throw an exception/error.

Comment: Why just that parameter... Why is that so important? What if someone sends `foo` or `whatEver`... Seems like you try to block something that shouldn't be blocked? What is the usecase here? You could add `params="!objectName,objectId"` to the `@PutMapping` if `objectName` is present it will not match and eventually throw a `404`.

Comment: @Zelocox so the use of RequestParam with required = false is not an option for your use case?

Comment: Thanks Guys !!! Actually the idea @M.Deinum suggested worked for me.
I simply tried params=!objectName and this worked.

Comment: However, the question still remains - How we can add a custom annotation for filtering out something which we do not want to go to controllerMethod. 
Something like a filter gets triggered only when a particular annotation is applied to the controller.

Comment: You can use a `HandlerInterceptor`, else you would need to write an extension for the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which knows what to do with that annotation.